# Visual Basic FileCopy error75 after Microsoft Office 2010 updates

Tags: excel, vba, security, batch-file, ms-office

Recently a large number of security updates were pushed for Microsoft Office at work. We have an Excel tool with a Visual Basic backbone which worked prior to the updates, and now does not work.

I have done some isolated testing and have found that we see the same 'error 75' when using the FileCopy method on .BAT and .EXE files. Other less 'risky' file types seem to be ok. This is also an issue with the 'Open' command.

Does anybody know of a workaround for this issue when copy/pasting .EXE and .BAT files, or maybe this is a known issue with a certain security update? I have searched everywhere, but the Google is failing me. I am hoping either:

1. Someone knows which security update is the culprit and I can try
   uninstalling it to see if that fixes the issue
2. There is a different way to copy/open/manipulate .BAT and .EXE files that doesn't violate the new security patch.

Some background: 
We are using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010 and the tool uses Excel as the interface.

Here is the testing code I am using. I have verified that .TXT and .DAT files run just fine while .EXE and .BAT files cause 'error 75' indicating a permissions error. And before you ask, yes, the file path is correct, I have just omitted my employee identification information.

```
Sub Macro1()
    ' Declare variables
    Dim Filename, SourcePath, DestPath As String

    ' Pathname variables
    Filename = "test.dat"
    SourcePath = "C:\Users\<REDACTED>\Desktop\working_copy\" & Filename
    DestPath = "C:\Users\<REDACTED>\Desktop\working_copy\test\" & Filename

    ' Copy file from Source and paste in Destination
    FileCopy SourcePath, DestPath
End Sub
```

Here is an image with the updates that were installed. The tool worked prior to the 6/14/2017 dump, so anything before can be disregarded.
Sorry for the image, too many to enter them manually, no easy way to copy from the update list:

[MS Office 2010 Security Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJgnj.png)

Nothing with the tool or file structure changed. The only thing different is the updates. Also, we tested the same tool with Microsoft Office Home 2016 and it worked without a hitch.

Any and all help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend not to uninstall any Security Updates. Please investigate more on the error you get. The Path may exist but do you have the permission to (over)ride the files where you want to put them? Are the files accessible? Maybe check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264531(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Yes, I have 'Full Control' permissions on all files, folders, and sub-folders I am attempting to access. Everything was working fine the day before the update and nothing in the tool or file structure changed. I just double checked to verify that the update didn't modify my permissions.

Comment: Do you have User Account Control (UAC) activated? If so does it work without? On my Windows 8.1 without UAC activated both `.exe` as well as `.bat` worked.

Comment: Not sure. I will have to wait on IT to do it for me, so hopefully I can check today. Thanks. I will let you know.

Comment: FYI: UAC was deactivated. Thank you for the suggestion. IT opened a ticket to explore, but that was a month and a half ago so I'm not holding my breath. I found a work around though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I never found a real fix for this issue, I did come up with a slightly 'hacky' work-around.

The MS security patch prevented me from copy/pasting .BAT and .EXE files, I but could still save .BAT files.
So, I ended up having my script create a text file called "copyExe.txt" which had a single line:

```
ECHO F|xcopy <source> <destination>
```

This was then renamed to be "copyExe.bat" and run.

By creating a .txt file, I circumvented the errors when using the VBA Open function on .BAT files (so I could actually create this new batch file). This batch file has the sole purpose of copy/pasting a .EXE file from one folder to another, which circumvented errors when trying to copy/paste .EXE files.
After the copy/paste script is run, it is deleted.

All-in-all it feels like a very silly solution, but it works and is very non-invasive for the user.